# How to install Lotus 9?

Tags: dpkg, software-installation, ibm-lotus-notes

When I install notes 9 on my Ubuntu 13. 04 its not complete the installation because some depending package see below:

```
hassan@Hassan-Ubuntu:~/Downloads/IBM Notes 9$ sudo dpkg -i ibm-notes-9.0.i586.deb 
[sudo] password for hassan:
dpkg: regarding ibm-notes-9.0.i586.deb containing ibm-notes, pre-dependency problem:
 ibm-notes pre-depends on libgnomeprint2.2-0
dpkg: error processing ibm-notes-9.0.i586.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing ibm-notes
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ibm-notes-9.0.i586.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

My experience with IBM Notes 9 and 9.0.1 is that installing all required dependencies will break [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) and render your 64-bit Ubuntu installation unusable for the most part.

The reason is that the deb package as distributed by IBM is designed to be installed on 32-bit systems **only**.

However, you can fix the package dependencies to make it install properly and work flawlessly on your 64-bit Ubuntu. This is similar to [miquel](https://askubuntu.com/users/108245/miquel)'s approach [above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292008/lotus-9-on-ubuntu-13-04-64bit#310987), only that he removes *all dependencies*, while I'll modify them to be compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit Ubuntu versions.

Dependencies are mostly libraries the program is dynamically liked to, so I ran this command on an *32-bit* Ubuntu 12.04 with IBM Notes installed:

```
$ for f in $(find /opt/ibm/ -type f -exec ldd {} \; | grep -v executable | fgrep -v libc.so.6 | sed 's/\([^(]*\)(.*)$/\1/' | grep i386-linux-gnu | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq ); do apt-file search $f; done | grep -v dbg | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | sed 's/:$//'
```

This was the output:

```
libart-2.0-2            libgconf-2-4            libnspr4             libx11-6              zlib1g
libasound2              libgcrypt11             libnspr4-0d          libxau6
libatk1.0-0             libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0      libnss3              libxcb1
libavahi-client3        libglib2.0-0            libnss3-1d           libxcb-render0
libavahi-common3        libgnome2-0             libogg0              libxcb-shm0
libavahi-glib1          libgnomecanvas2-0       liborbit2            libxcomposite1
libbonobo2-0            libgnome-keyring0       libp11-kit0          libxcursor1
libbonoboui2-0          libgnomeui-0            libpam0g             libxdamage1
libc6                   libgnomevfs2-0          libpango1.0-0        libxdmcp6
libcairo2               libgnutls26             libpcre3             libxext6
libcanberra0            libgpg-error0           libpixman-1-0        libxfixes3
libcomerr2              libgssapi-krb5-2        libpng12-0           libxft2
libcups2                libgtk2.0-0             libpopt0             libxi6
libdbus-1-3             libhunspell-1.3-0       libselinux1          libxinerama1
libdbus-glib-1-2        libice6                 libsm6               libxml2
libexpat1               libjpeg62               libstdc++6           libxp6
libffi6                 libk5crypto3            libtasn1-3           libxrandr2
libfontconfig1          libkeyutils1            libtdb1              libxrender1
libfreetype6            libkrb5-3               libuuid1             libxss1
libgail18               libkrb5support0         libvorbis0a          libxt6
libgcc1                 libltdl7                libvorbisfile3       libxtst6
```

Then I untar'd IBM Notes:

```
$ tar --extract --file /path/to/NOTES_9.0.1_LINUX_DI_EN_Evaluation.tar --directory ~/Desktop
```

extracted the package's contents:

```
$ mkdir ~/Desktop/repackage
$ cp ~/Desktop/ibm-notes-9.0.1.i586.deb ~/Desktop/repackage/
$ cd ~/Desktop/repackage/
$ dpkg-deb -x ibm-notes-9.0.1.i586.deb common
$ dpkg-deb --control ibm-notes-9.0.1.i586.deb
```

and edited the deb package's control file:

```
$ vi DEBIAN/control
```

to replace the default dependencies with the list above (plus some additions). This is the modified control file:

```
Package: ibm-notes
Version: 9.0.1-20131022.1138
Section: Office
Priority: extra
Architecture: i386
Pre-Depends: gdb:i386 | gdb:amd64, coreutils:i386 | coreutils:amd64, unzip:i386 | unzip:amd64, bash:i386 | bash:amd64, procps:i386 | procps:amd64, grep:i386 | grep:amd64, sed:i386 | sed:amd64, libart-2.0-2:i386, libasound2:i386, libatk1.0-0:i386, libavahi-client3:i386, libavahi-common3:i386, libavahi-glib1:i386, libbonobo2-0:i386, libbonoboui2-0:i386, libc6:i386, libcairo2:i386, libcanberra0:i386, libcomerr2:i386, libcups2:i386, libdbus-1-3:i386, libdbus-glib-1-2:i386, libexpat1:i386, libffi6:i386, libfontconfig1:i386, libfreetype6:i386, libgail18:i386, libgcc1:i386, libgconf-2-4:i386, libgcrypt11:i386, libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386, libglib2.0-0:i386, libgnome2-0:i386, libgnomecanvas2-0:i386, libgnome-keyring0:i386, libgnomeui-0:i386, libgnomevfs2-0:i386, libgnutls26:i386, libgpg-error0:i386, libgssapi-krb5-2:i386, libgtk2.0-0:i386, libhunspell-1.3-0:i386, libice6:i386, libjpeg62:i386, libk5crypto3:i386, libkeyutils1:i386, libkrb5-3:i386, libkrb5support0:i386, libltdl7:i386, libnspr4:i386, libnspr4-0d:i386, libnss3:i386, libnss3-1d:i386, libogg0:i386, liborbit2:i386, libp11-kit0:i386, libpam0g:i386, libpango1.0-0:i386, libpcre3:i386, libpixman-1-0:i386, libpng12-0:i386, libpopt0:i386, libselinux1:i386, libsm6:i386, libstdc++6:i386, libtasn1-3:i386 | libtasn1-4:i386 | libtasn1-5:i386 | libtasn1-6:i386, libtdb1:i386, libuuid1:i386, libvorbis0a:i386, libvorbisfile3:i386, libx11-6:i386, libxau6:i386, libxcb1:i386, libxcb-render0:i386, libxcb-shm0:i386, libxcomposite1:i386, libxcursor1:i386, libxdamage1:i386, libxdmcp6:i386, libxext6:i386, libxfixes3:i386, libxft2:i386, libxi6:i386, libxinerama1:i386, libxml2:i386, libxp6:i386, libxrandr2:i386, libxrender1:i386, libxss1:i386, libxt6:i386, libxtst6:i386, zlib1g:i386, unity-gtk2-module:i386, libcanberra-gtk-module:i386, libxss1:i386, gtk2-engines-murrine:i386, p11-kit-modules:i386, libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386, ttf-xfree86-nonfree:i386 | ttf-xfree86-nonfree:amd64
Conflicts: ibm-notes-hotfix, ibm-notes-fixpack (<< 8.5.4), ibm-lotus-activities, ibm-lotus-cae, ibm-cae, ibm-lotus-feedreader, ibm-lotus-sametime, ibm-lotus-symphony, ibm-lotus-notes-fixpack, ibm-lotus-notes-hotfix, ibm-lotus-notes
Replaces: ibm-notes-fixpack, ibm-lotus-activities, ibm-lotus-cae, ibm-cae, ibm-lotus-feedreader, ibm-lotus-sametime, ibm-lotus-symphony, ibm-lotus-notes-fixpack, ibm-lotus-notes-hotfix, ibm-lotus-notes
Installed-Size: 830544
Maintainer: IBM Product <sw_support@us.ibm.com>
Description: IBM Notes
 IBM Notes software provides a robust and productive user experience with a single point of access to email, calendars, contacts, activities, instant messaging, feeds, collaboration tools, and business applications. Loaded with new features to help you work smarter, the new user interface presents the tools you need, when and where you need them. Plus, you get quick access to your business information in one integrated view, in the context of the work you're doing. That means you get your job done faster, and easier. You can also install the following optional features once you have installed IBM Notes: IBM Sametime, IBM Connections, IBM Feedreader, IBM OpenSocial.
```

> **Comments on the control file above:**
>
> The `Pre-Depends` section contains the package list generated on 12.04
>   with specific architecture information that makes it compatible with
>   32-bit and 64-bit versions.
>
> I also noticed that [Precise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precise_Pangolin#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29)'s `libtasn1-3` had been updated to
>   `libtasn1-6` on 14.04, so I added all version numbers between 1-3 and
>   1-6 to the control file. Some trial and error showed that other
>   software was needed, like `libcanberra,` `libp11` and so on, which I
>   included. I also left dependencies to `gdb`, `coreutils`, etc, but accepting
>   both architectures.

I copied the modified `DEBIAN` folder to `common`:

```
$ cp -a DEBIAN common
```

recreated the package:

```
$ dpkg -b common ibm-notes-9.0.1.i586.deb
```

installed dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libart-2.0-2:i386 libasound2:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libavahi-glib1:i386 libbonobo2-0:i386 libbonoboui2-0:i386 libc6:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcanberra0:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgail18:i386 libgcc1:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgnome2-0:i386 libgnomecanvas2-0:i386 libgnome-keyring0:i386 libgnomeui-0:i386 libgnomevfs2-0:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libhunspell-1.3-0:i386 libice6:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 libltdl7:i386 libnspr4:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 libnss3:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libogg0:i386 liborbit2:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpam0g:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpopt0:i386 libselinux1:i386 libsm6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtdb1:i386 libuuid1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxft2:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386 libxp6:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxtst6:i386 zlib1g:i386 unity-gtk2-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libxss1:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 p11-kit-modules:i386 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 ttf-xfree86-nonfree
(...)
0 upgraded, 139 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 19.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 70.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

and installed IBM Notes:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ibm-notes-9.0.1.i586.deb
```

Note that you will have to start Notes several times while setting it up. I even had to kill it once as it hung while connecting to the Domino server, but it runs without a hitch on my Trusty Tahr (14.04) installation.

Comment: Where I can get this binary?

Comment: To get `ibm-notes-9.0.1.i586.deb` download `NOTES_9.0.1_LINUX_DI_EN_Evaluation.tar` from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/lsndad/index.html. You need an IBM ID, if you don't have one create it in the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You required the dependent files first.

Use

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs libgnomeprint2.2-0:i386 libgnomeprintui2.2-0:i386 libgnomevfs2-bin:i386 libgnome2-0:i386 libgnomeui-0:i386 libjpeg62:i386
```

Then try installing using

`sudo dpkg –force-depends -i ibm-notes-9.0.i586.deb`

Source & More information available [here](http://usablesoftware.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/quick-guide-installing-notes-9-on-ubuntu-13-04-beta1-64bit/).

Comment: ok i installed last command but after reinstall notes 9 i have a following error :

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibm-notes:

 ibm-notes depends on gdb; however:

Answer (score 0):

I had problems also installing Lotus Notes 9 on ubuntu. Try this if you're on 64 bits (based on usable software's blog solution). You'll have to unpack the deb file, remove the dependencies and install it again. There's no need to --force-depends if you do it this way:

http://myotragusbalearicus.wordpress.com/2013/06/21/install-lotus-notes-9-on-ubuntu-13-04-64-bits/

Answer (score 0):

I would comment if I could.. but here's what you need to do:

1. Continue to try and install with `dpkg`
2. Each time you get an error, you need to read the error for the package missing
3. Install the missing package using `sudo apt-get install $PACKAGE_NAME`. **NOTE:** You can put multiple package names in this command
4. Repeat steps until package installs.

Unfortunately, `dpkg` does not have a package manager within, but is just the barebones package installer that applications like `apt` use to do the install work.

It looks like the alternative, which may be better, is to use `gdebi-gtk` to install your package. It will resolve your dependency problems. I've never used it, so might as well try it and let us know if it works. It *should* be faster than doing it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Add this software source to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

Run this command for installing dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libgnomeprint2.2-0:i386 libgnomeprintui2.2-0:i386 libbonobo2-0:i386 libbonoboui2-0:i386 libgconf2-4:i386 libgnome-desktop-2-17:i386 libgnomevfs2-bin:i386 libgnomeui-0:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libpam0g:i386 libxkbfile1:i386 ttf-xfree86-nonfree t1-xfree86-nonfree

sudo dpkg -i ibm-notes-repackage-9.0.i586.deb
```

Run command:

```
apt-get install -f install
```

Install other .debs in the following way:

```
sudo dpkg -i ibm-cae-9.0.i586.deb
sudo dpkg -i ibm-feedreader-9.0.i586.deb
sudo dpkg -i ibm-connections-4.5.0.i586.deb 
sudo dpkg -i ibm-activities-9.0.i586.deb
sudo dpkg -i ibm-opensocial-9.0.i586.deb
sudo dpkg -i ibm-sametime-9.0.i586.deb
```